# Product Count all with same Categorie ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Sidebar Menu and i want count all Products with same categorie ID from my mysql DB table.

I have 3 Products in DB  "products - category_id" with the ID "1"

My code that shows only the category_id for one product

```
<div class="panel-heading">

 {{$product->category_id}} 


</div>
```

RESULT IN PHP = 1

How can i count all Products with the  category_id "1"?

RESULT IN PHP I WANT = 3

Comment: show your code, query please.

Comment: `SELECT
 COUNT(*) as product_count
FROM 
 products
WHERE
 category_id = 1`     should be the query

Comment: thanks and sorry for the question: how can i display it in php between my div class ?

Comment: have to be something like {{$query->product_count}} where $query is your query